# Merging attributes with XSLT

Tags: xml, xslt, msbuild

I'm an absolute newbie at XSLT, and have cobbled together the following over the last couple of hours with the help of google. So be warned...

Sample file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Project DefaultTargets="Build" ToolsVersion="4.0" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
  <PropertyGroup Label="Globals">
    <ProjectGuid>{C7D20737-FF45-4232-8461-34C6B5B9D1E5}</ProjectGuid>
    <PlatformToolset>v110</PlatformToolset>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <Import Project="toinline.proj" />
</Project>
```

toinline.proj

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <Project DefaultTargets="Build" ToolsVersion="4.0" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003" InitialTargets="Stuff">
      <Stuff></Stuff>
    </Project>
```

Basically, what I want to do is to create an XSLT program which does a relatively simple transformation: Given an MSBuild project file (which is an XML file), I want to 'inline' the top-level `Import` tag (the tag references a file using a relative path, I want to take the contents of top level tag in that file, and replace the tag with that)).

For the given example, I'm expecting something like

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Project DefaultTargets="Build" ToolsVersion="4.0" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
  <PropertyGroup Label="Globals">
    <ProjectGuid>{C7D20737-FF45-4232-8461-34C6B5B9D1E5}</ProjectGuid>
    <PlatformToolset>v110</PlatformToolset>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <Stuff></Stuff>
</Project>
```

I've got that working with the following

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:msb="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
  <xsl:output indent="yes"/>
  <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

  <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <!-- Replace any 'import' tag with the contents of the project file it references.
       Note that this only works with relative paths. -->
  <xsl:template match="msb:Import">
    <xsl:copy-of select="document(@Project)/msb:Project/*"/>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Now, the problem I have is that the file which I am inlining ('toinline.proj' in the sample) itself has a top-level `Project` tag, with an `InitialTargets` attribute, which I would like to 'merge' into the enclosing document, to end up with something like

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Project DefaultTargets="Build" ToolsVersion="4.0" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003" InitialTargets="Stuff">
  <PropertyGroup Label="Globals">
    <ProjectGuid>{C7D20737-FF45-4232-8461-34C6B5B9D1E5}</ProjectGuid>
    <PlatformToolset>v110</PlatformToolset>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <Stuff></Stuff>
</Project>
```

How can I extend my solution to do this? For now I can assume that the enclosing document didn't have that attribute, but ideally if it did, we would merge the contents (by concatenating with a semicolon)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Declare a global variable bound to the referenced document:

```
<xsl:variable name="importee" select="document(//Import/@Project)"/>
```

Then use this in your existing template rule:

```
<xsl:template match="msb:Import">
    <xsl:copy-of select="$importee/msb:Project/*"/>
</xsl:template>
```

and add one more template rule:

```
<xsl:template match="msb:Projects">
  <xsl:copy>
    <xsl:copy-of select="@*"/> 
    <xsl:attribute name="InitialTargets" select="$importee/msb:Projects/@InitiaTargets"/>
    <xsl:apply-templates/>
  </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

PS:
I should have mentioned that `xsl:attribute/@select` is XSLT 2.0 syntax. If you have the misfortune to be using 1.0, you need xsl:attribute with an xsl:value-of child instruction. On SO posts, please always say which version you are using since the solution can sometimes be very different.

Comment: When trying your solution, I get the following error from msbuild: `error MSB3704: Unable to load the specified Xslt. 'select' is an invalid attribute for the 'xsl:attribute' element.`, would that be caused by an older version of the language? I'm using the `XslTransformation` task in msbuild, not sure what version that uses.

Comment: This doesn't seem to work - it seems like my tag is replaced by.... nothing, and I don't get the attribute either. No errors, just seems like `$importee` evaluates to nothing.

Comment: Oh, this is after using `<xsl:attribute name="InitialTargets">
        <xsl:value-of select="$importee/msb:Projects/@InitialTargets" />
      </xsl:attribute>`

Comment: Nevermind, my trouble was just typos and lack of namespaces, it works now, thanks!